# reduce the spacing between the drawable and the text

Tags: android, textview

How can I reduce the spacing between the `DrawableLeft` and the text in a `TextView`

I can use setting `drawablePadding` to 0 didn't help.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/small_bg"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/mypic"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="25"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Make sure the image itself has no padding.

Comment: Can you post your xml and image.

Comment: post both code and an image

Answer (score 4):

set **drawablePadding** to a **negative** value

```
android:drawablePadding="-8dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

You already set the padding for the TextView to 4dp
try this:

```
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
```

instead of:

```
android:padding="4dp"
```